# delete URL request in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm going through node js(first server side language) book called Node js in action. There is an example on restful services implementation using cURL. I don't understand how to send delete request url to server. I've tried different combination to make it work but couldn't  find one. I guess, it could be because of my less understanding of URL request. Below is the code

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var items = [];
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
switch(req.method){
    case 'POST':
        var item="";
        req.setEncoding('utf-8');
        req.on('data', function (chunk){
            item+=chunk;
        });
        req.on('end', function (){
            items.push(item);
            res.end();
        });
        break;
    case 'GET':
        items.forEach(function (item, i){
            res.write(i+') '+item+'\n');
        });
        res.end();
        break;
    case 'DELETE' : 
        var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
        var i = parseInt(path.slice(1),10);
        if(isNaN(i)){
            res.statusCode = 400;
            res.end('Invalid argument !');
        }
        else if(!items[i]){
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.end('Item not found');
        }
        else{
            items.splice(i,1);
            res.end('Deleted!');
        }
  }
 }).listen(3000);
```

If possible, can someone explain me how this URL request work.

Comment: From your other question is looks like you're using cURL to test your stuff, you can supply the http method parameter with the `-X` option, i.e. `-X DELETE`.

Comment: Question unclear. Are you asking how to send a delete request or how to handle one in node.js?

Comment: how do i delete the items from the list? I've tried different curl commands, couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem as well while working my way through the book, NodeJS in Action. To perform a delete request with curl, I typed this into the terminal.

curl -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/1

The number on the end being the index number of the list item I wished to delete.